Stop wearing gold crown?
Does a monarch from a nation that has Crown Jewels including a gold 
crown (and what not) who converts (or reverts) need to stop wearing his gold crown after he converts to Islam?

Wearing gold jewellery for men is forbidden. Why would this be any different?

Interesting thought, and UmH has already answered your literal question in a the above comment. But, say, just as a thought experiment: what if King Charles would convert to Islam? He could not give up the Crown, but would not be allowed to wear it. But he could carry it in front of him, symbolizing he is only a servant in charge of the kingdom. The cheers would be endless. But if he puts away his wedding ring, I really would fear for his life.

Good point on the ring

I feel King Charles is a particular case due to the idol cross atop.

"... due to the idol cross atop." ... ah he didn't pay me nor hire me as a consultant. But I he would (and would convert to Islam in the first place, which I have reasons to doubt, it is a thought experiment), I would counsel him to interpret this that he rules the Christians in his country as well as before.

I had to think multiple times why you call it an "idol cross". Is it because you see Trinity as idol worship? Putting not one, but two next to Allah?

I feel driven to add another comment about the hypothetical conversion of king Charles to Islam: there are some people up there in Ulster who are very tolerant about other peoples religious believes. But only if those believes match their own believes very exactly.  And they know about high explosives for a long time and would turn from pro-monarchic to anti-monarchic in just no time.
